# How to write the SQL statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have 2 tables (assume ID is the key) and used nested loop in my codes and it worked fine.

```
select * from table1 where table1.ID in 
(select ID from table2 where status='ACTIVE')
```

The SQL above could be converted to Linq as below:

```
from a in table1
join b in table2 on a.ID == b.ID
where b.status="ACTIVE"
select a;
```

But now what I am looking for is the other half of the result.

```
select * from table1 where table1.ID NOT in 
(select ID from table2 where status='ACTIVE')
```

Please note the "NOT" in the statement above.

Can any one help?

Comment: same as first Linq except... `where b.status != "ACTIVE"` doesn't give desired result?

Comment: No. It doesn't. Because it is a one-many relationship between table 1 and 2. Changing == to != returns more records than I need.

Comment: Never mind. I got the answer from other posts. Thank you all.